# How to replace radio buttons with images

Tags: javascript, html

How do I fix this code so that the images show up. They aren't showing up where the radio buttons used to be. I've tried several different methods on different occassions and this seems to be the most promising but I just can't seem to make the images appear where they should. Please don't tell me how many times this was answered because you don't know how many attempts I gave MANY of them. I just want help with getting the images in place of the radio buttons with javascript. Please use jsfiddle for examples. I may be missing labels but I don't know where to put them.
http://jsfiddle.net/uuyAq/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <script>

    var images = {
1: 'http://wepriceit.webs.com/ipad-5-image.jpg',
2: 'http://wepriceit.webs.com/ipad-5-image.jpg',
3: 'http://wepriceit.webs.com/ipad-5-image.jpg',
4: 'http://wepriceit.webs.com/ipad-5-image.jpg',
5: 'http://wepriceit.webs.com/ipad-5-image.jpg'
};

$('input[type=radio][name^=question]').each(function() {
var id = this.id;
$(this)
      .hide()  // hide the radio button
      .after('<img src="'+ images[id] +'">'); // insert the image 
                                              // after corresponding radio
});

</script>
</head>
<body>

<script>
function tryToMakeLink()
{
    //get all selected radios
    var q1=document.querySelector('input[name="q1"]:checked');
    var q2=document.querySelector('input[name="q2"]:checked');
    var q3=document.querySelector('input[name="q3"]:checked');
    //make sure the user has selected all 3
    if (q1==null || q2==null ||q3==null)
    {
        document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML="<input type=button 
disabled=disabled value=Next>";
    }
    else
    {
        //now we know we have 3 radios, so get their values
        q1=q1.value;
        q2=q2.value;
        q3=q3.value;
        //now check the values to display a different link for the desired   
configuration
        if (q1=="AT&T" && q2=="8GB" && q3=="Black")
        {
          document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML="<input type=button value=Next  
onclick=\"window.location.href='http://google.com/';\">att 8gb black</input>";
        }
        else if (q1=="Other" && q2=="8GB" && q3=="White")
        {
            document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML="<input type=button value=Next 
onclick=\"window.location.href='http://yahoo.com/';\">other 8b white</input>";
        }
        else if (q1=="AT&T" && q2=="16GB" && q3=="White")
        {
            document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML="<input type=button value=Next 
onclick=\"window.location.href='http://bing.com/';\">another option</input>";
        }
        else if (q1=="AT&T" && q2=="16GB" && q3=="Black")
        {
            document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML="<input type=button value=Next 
onclick=\"window.location.href='http://gmail.com/';\">oops</input>";
        }
        else if (q1=="AT&T" && q2=="8GB" && q3=="White")
        {
            document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML="<input type=button value=Next 
onclick=\"window.location.href='http://hotmail.com/';\">can't</input>";
        }
        else if (q1=="Other" && q2=="8GB" && q3=="Black")
        {
          document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML="<input type=button value=Next 
onclick=\"window.location.href='http://images.google.com/';\">yours</input>";
        }
        else if (q1=="Other" && q2=="16GB" && q3=="White")
        {
            document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML="<input type=button value=Next 
onclick=\"window.location.href='http://youtube.com/';\">mines</input>";
        }
        else if (q1=="Other" && q2=="16GB" && q3=="Black")
        {
            document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML="<input type=button value=Next 
onclick=\"window.location.href='http://docs.google.com/';\">what</input>";
        }
        else if (q1=="Unlocked" && q2=="8GB" && q3=="White")
        {
            document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML="<input type=button value=Next 
onclick=\"window.location.href='http://wepriceit.webs.com/';\">red</input>";
        }
        else if (q1=="Unlocked" && q2=="8GB" && q3=="Black")
        {
            document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML="<input type=button value=Next 
onclick=\"window.location.href='http://webs.com/';\">orange</input>";
        }
        else if (q1=="Unlocked" && q2=="16GB" && q3=="White")
        {
            document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML="<input type=button value=Next 
onclick=\"window.location.href='http://gazelle.com/';\">green</input>";
        }
        else if (q1=="Unlocked" && q2=="16GB" && q3=="Black")
        {
            document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML="<input type=button value=Next 
onclick=\"window.location.href='http://glyde.com/';\">blue</input>";
        }
    }
}
</script>

<form name="quiz" id='quiz'>


What carrier do you have?
<ul style="margin-top: 1pt" id="navlist">
    <li style="list-style: none;"><input type="radio" onclick=tryToMakeLink();   
name="q1" value="AT&T" id="1"/>AT&T</li><label for="1"/>
    <li style="list-style: none;"><input type="radio" onclick=tryToMakeLink(); 
name="q1" value="Other" id="2"/>Other</li><label for="2"/>
    <li style="list-style: none;"><input type="radio" onclick=tryToMakeLink(); 
name="q1" value="Unlocked" id="3"/>Unlocked</li><label for="3"/>
</ul>

What is your phones capicity?
<ul style="margin-top: 1pt" id="navlist">
    <li style="list-style: none;"><input type="radio" onclick=tryToMakeLink(); 
name="q2" value="8GB" id="4"/>8GB</li><label for="4"/>
    <li style="list-style: none;"><input type="radio" onclick=tryToMakeLink(); 
name="q2" value="16GB" id="5"/>16GB</li><label for="5"/>
</ul>

What color is your phone?
<ul style="margin-top: 1pt" id="navlist">
    <li style="list-style: none;"><input type="radio" onclick=tryToMakeLink(); 
name="q3" value="Black" id="6"/>Black</li><label for="6"/>
    <li style="list-style: none;"><input type="radio" onclick=tryToMakeLink();  
name="q3" value="White" id="7"/>White</li><label for="7"/>
</ul>



<br>
<div id=linkDiv>
 <input type=button disabled=disabled value=Next>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uuyAq/

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using Javascript? There is a pure CSS solution to this!

Step one - the HTML:

```
<input type="radio" class="radio" name="radio" id="radio"> <label for="radio">Option</label>
```

Step two - the CSS:

```
/* visually hide the default radio button */
.radio {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
}

/* make the label relative, add padding to the left for adding the custom radio button */
.radio + label {
    padding-left: 23px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin: 8px 0;
}

/* :before will be our new button! */

.radio + label:before {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 16px;
    -moz-border-radius: 16px;
    border-radius: 16px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transition(background 250ms ease-in-out);
    -moz-transition(background 250ms ease-in-out);
    -o-transition(background 250ms ease-in-out);
    transition(background 250ms ease-in-out);

    /* Your size */
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    /* This should be: 0 - (height / 2) */
    margin-top: -5px;
    /* Your default background color */
    background: #f97e76;
}

.radio:checked + label:before {
    /* Your checked background color */
    background: #a8bd44;
}
```

Granted it's a lot of CSS, but it's hell of a better solution than using Javascript.

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ninty9notout/GsSvF/

Shameless self plug - this is a page I made using pure CSS to change the appearance of radios and checkboxes: http://hieroishere.com/flatui/

This method uses pseudo-elements. You can read about them:

On CSS Play: http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-element-roundup/

On MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

Your selector `$('input[type=radio][name^=question]')` looks for checkboxes with names starting with "question" but the form contains elements with names like `q1`, `q2` ...

Comment: so instead of "question" I need to put [name^="q1 q2 q3"]) in it's place?

Comment: Well, you can start by using `$('input[type=radio][name^=q]')` as the selector, but that alone won't make too much of a difference. Your JSfiddle is configured to rum with mootools. Is that your intention? If you want to use jQuery you need to put the settings in place (left side).

Comment: ... and, of course, you can only add things to your DOM once the DOM is ready, so, on your page (different to JSfiddle) put the code in the `jQuery(function(){ /* put code here ... */ })` section.

Answer (score 0):

I just googled it, and found this: http://so.devilmaycode.it/is-there-an-easy-way-to-replace-radio-button-with-images-and-a-colored-border-fo/ which is an answer to a similar question.

JS/JQ:

```
    $(function () {
    $('input:radio').hide().each(function () {
        var label = $("label[for=" + '"' + this.id + '"' + "]").text();
        $('<a ' + (label != '' ? 'title=" ' + label + ' "' : '') + ' class="radio-fx ' + this.name + '" href="#"><span class="radio' + (this.checked ? ' radio-checked' : '') + '"></span></a>').insertAfter(this);
    });
    $('.radio-fx').on('click', function (e) {
        $check = $(this).prev('input:radio');
        var unique = '.' + this.className.split(' ')[1] + ' span';
        $(unique).attr('class', 'radio');
        $(this).find('span').attr('class', 'radio-checked');
        $check.attr('checked', true);
    }).on('keydown', function (e) {
        if ((e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which) == 32) {
            $(this).trigger('click');
        }
    });
    /* not needed just for sake ;)*/
    $('#form').submit(function () {
        var posts = $(this).serialize();
        if (posts != '') {
            alert(posts);
        } else {
            alert('please select something, then submit the form!');
        }
        return false;
    });
    $('#change-skin').change(function () {
        $('form table').attr('id', this.value);
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
   body {
        font-family: Trebuchet, "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
        text-align: center
    }
    form {
        text-align: left;
        width: 310px;
        margin: 20px auto
    }
    a.radio-fx span, a.radio-fx {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
    }
    #skin_1 .radio, #skin_1 .radio-checked, #skin_1 a.radio-fx {
        width: 32px;
        height: 32px;
    }
    #skin_2 .radio, #skin_2 .radio-checked, #skin_2 a.radio-fx {
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
    }
    #skin_3 .radio, #skin_3 .radio-checked, #skin_3 a.radio-fx {
        width: 24px;
        height: 24px;
    }
    #skin_1 .radio {
        background: url(http://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/32x32_0160/bullet_red.png) no-repeat;
    }
    #skin_1 .radio-checked {
        background: url(http://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/32x32_0160/bullet_green.png) no-repeat;
    }
    #skin_2 .radio {
        background: url(http://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/uidesignicons/radiobutton_no.png) no-repeat;
    }
    #skin_2 .radio-checked {
        background: url(http://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/uidesignicons/radiobutton_yes.png) no-repeat;
    }
    #skin_3 .radio {
        background: url(http://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/icojoy/noshadow/standart/png/24x24/001_05.png) no-repeat;
    }
    #skin_3 .radio-checked {
        background: url(http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/icojoy/noshadow/standart/gif/24x24/001_06.gif) no-repeat;
    }
    table {
        width: 300px;
        border: 1px solid #CCC;
        padding: 5px;
        background: whiteSmoke
    }
    td {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    h1 a, h2 a{
        color: inherit;
    }
```

HTML

```
<h1><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112995/is-there-an-easy-way-to-replace-radio-button-with-images-and-a-colored-border-fo" class="question-hyperlink">Stackoverflow: Is there an easy way to replace radio button with Images (and a colored border
    for selected)</a></h1>
<h2><a href="so.devilmaycode.it/is-there-an-easy-way-to-replace-radio-button-with-images-and-a-colored-border-fo/">Original: http://so.devilmaycode.it/is-there-an-easy-way-to-replace-radio-button-with-images-and-a-colored-border-fo/#</a></h2>

<form id="form">
    <table id="skin_1" summary="layout table">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="music" value="1" />
            </td>
            <td>music 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="music" value="2" checked="checked" />
            </td>
            <td>music 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="music" value="3" />
            </td>
            <td>music 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="music" value="4" />
            </td>
            <td>music 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=2>
                <hr />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="stereo" value="1" />
            </td>
            <td>stereo 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="stereo" value="2" />
            </td>
            <td>stereo 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="stereo" value="3" />
            </td>
            <td>stereo 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="stereo" value="4" />
            </td>
            <td>stereo 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=2>
                <hr />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="change-skin">
                    <option value="skin_1">skin 1</option>
                    <option value="skin_2">skin 2</option>
                    <option value="skin_3">skin 3</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Anyway, I put it in a jsfiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/B63PH/.