# CSS Html make a image appear over options of a radio button ( radio button is hidden by CSS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make an image appear over options of a radio button ( radio button is hidden by CSS)
PLs check the following js fiddle

[a link] (https://jsfiddle.net/testingmilan56/rqr4dt8h/)

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
input {
    visibility:hidden;
}
label {
    cursor: pointer;
}
input:checked + label {
    background:#fff000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type='radio' value='1' name='radio' id='radio1'/>
        <label for='radio1'>Value 1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type='checkbox' value='2' name='radio'  id='radio2'/>
        <label for='radio2'>Value 2</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type='radio' value='3' name='radio'  id='radio3'/>
        <label for='radio3'>Value 3</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I also want to control the position of the image .I know its possible to do with z-index ..please help .A slight modification is required .

## thanks

Comment: I don't see any images in your supplied code? Can you provide us with an example of exactly what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: pls goto  ipsy dot com  and see the quiz .No there is no image yet in my code .i can add image later .

Comment: what have you tried so far? just providing the css and html doesn't show us how you approached the topic. help is only given to those, that already tried but failed ...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, but instead of playing with borders, box-shadows and background-colors, use background-images.

```css
.container {
  margin: 32px auto;
}
input {
  display: none;
}
label {
  display: block;
}
input + label:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  content: '';
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black;
  margin-right: 0.25em;
  top: .2em;
}

input:checked + label:before {
  border: 2px solid white;
  background: lime;;
}

input[type=radio] + label:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" id="check-1" name="check-1" />
  <label for="check-1">Label 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check-2" name="check-2" />
  <label for="check-2">Label 2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check-3" name="check-3" />
  <label for="check-3">Label 3</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check-4" name="check-4" />
  <label for="check-4">Label 4</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check-5" name="check-5" />
  <label for="check-5">Label 5</label>

  <hr />

  <input type="radio" id="radio-1" name="radio" />
  <label for="radio-1">label 1</label>
  <input type="radio" id="radio-2" name="radio" />
  <label for="radio-2">label 2</label>
  <input type="radio" id="radio-3" name="radio" />
  <label for="radio-3">label 3</label>
  <input type="radio" id="radio-4" name="radio" />
  <label for="radio-4">label 4</label>
  <input type="radio" id="radio-5" name="radio" />
  <label for="radio-5">label 5</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type='radio' value='1' name='radio' id='radio1'/>
        <label for='radio1'>Value 1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type='checkbox' value='2' name='radio'  id='radio2'/>
        <label for='radio2'>Value 2</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type='radio' value='3' name='radio'  id='radio3'/>
        <label for='radio3'>Value 3</label>
    </li>
</ul>

ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
li {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
}
input {
    visibility:hidden;
}
label {
    cursor: pointer;
}
input + label{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
input + label:before {
    background: #fff000;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
    bottom: 25px;
    left: 50%;
    display: block;
    content: '';
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: -35px;
}
input:checked + label:before {    
   content: 'TICK';    
}
```

You can use `FontAwesome` for `tick`, instead of image

https://jsfiddle.net/rqr4dt8h/1/

Answer (score 0):

Refer these Link: [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112995/how-to-replace-replace-radio-buttons-with-images)

```css
    .radio_item {
      display: none !important;
    }
    .label_item {
      opacity: 0.1;
    }
    .radio_item:checked + label {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    label {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
<!--RADIO 1-->
<input type="radio" class="radio_item" value="" name="item" id="radio1">
<label class="label_item" for="radio1">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSN1q.png">
</label>

<!--RADIO 2-->
<input type="radio" class="radio_item" value="" name="item" id="radio2">
<label class="label_item" for="radio2">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSN1q.png">
</label>
```