# Custom Radio and Checkbox using CSS

Tags: jquery, css, forms, checkbox, radio-button

is there a way to style the radio button and checkbox using custom images. using just CSS ?

Can some one point me how it can be done ?

Else which are the best plugins for jquery to do so ?

Comment: Read this: http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/ It should get you started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [CSS - Styling Checkboxes, Radio buttons & dropdowns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125226/css-styling-checkboxes-radio-buttons-dropdowns)

Answer (score 3):

jQuery UI has some excellent and easily implementable  options:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#checkbox

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with pure css3, using the pseudo class `:checked`. Inspired by this [article](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/c/checked/) I got the following solution:

Features:

- only css
- no `id` attribute needed
- no z-index needed

Try it on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tlindig/n6by8/6/

HTML:

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="rg"/><i></i>
    option 1
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" checked name="rg"/><i></i>
    option 2
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="rg"/><i></i>
    option 3
</label>
```

CSS:

```
input[type="radio"] {
    display:none;
}
input[type="radio"] + i:before {
    content:'\2718';
    color:red;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + i:before {
    content:'\2713';
    color:green;
}
```

Some explanations:

Element `i` is needed to add pseudo element `:before` with the icon as content. `input` elements are empty tags and can not have pseudo elements like `:before` and `:after` so we need a extra element. You could also use `span` or `div`, but `i` is shorter.

`label` is needed to trigger the `input`. If you wrap the `input` with a `label` element, you do not need `id` and `for` attributes for association.

'\2718' and '\2713' are UTF8 character codes for "ballot X" and "check mark".

Instead of `content` you could also set a `background-image` or what ever you like.

It works in all modern browsers and ie9+.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you'll be able to do this with pure CSS, but this way is great way with javascript:

http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

Answer (score 1):

Checkout **[WTF, forms](http://wtfforms.com/)** from a creator of Bootstrap [Mark otto](https://twitter.com/mdo/). It has good styles for checkbox and radio.