# Updating visual cue of checkbox state via code in jQuery

Tags: jquery-ui

I have the following HTML on my page:

```
 <input id="chkIncludeCA3" type="checkbox" /><label for="chkIncludeCA3">Category 3:</label>
```

And on my code page, the following piece of script:

```
$('#chkIncludeCA3').prop('checked', true);
```

Can someone explain to me how I would also update the visual state of the label to show that the checkbox is indeed checked?

*EDIT*

Thanks to Christophe Roussy for the correct pointer, have discovered the following works perfect:

```
$('#chkIncludeCA3').prop('checked', true); $("label[for='chkIncludeCA3']").addClass('ui-state-active');
```

If anyone knows if there is a more official way, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this to get the label ?!

```
$("label[for='chkIncludeCA3']")
```

Comment: Well yes, I guess that works, but I need to change visual state to reflect that fact that the underlying checkbox is checked.  I can't seem to see what style is used to determine this.

Comment: What do you mean by visual state ? CSS ?

Comment: Yes, sorry, the CSS style which toggles to show the state of the checkbox.

Comment: Well then you have a CSS problem, maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125226/styling-checkboxes-radio-buttons-and-dropdowns

Comment: Well I'm using the standard jqueryUI, no 3rd party so just want to toggle the inbuilt style, BUT, thanks to your help, I've managed to find a solution.  My thanks.