# checkbox not show checking after -webkit-appearance: none;

Tags: css, html

```
 .ajax-login-default-form-container input[type="checkbox"]{
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height:17px;
  width:17px;
  color:#000;
  background: #FFF;
  -webkit-appearance: none;

}
```

after adding this style, my check box don't show checked. Whats up?

tom

Comment: I tell my doctor, "It hurts when I do that."  Doctor says, "Then don't do that!"

Comment: You are removing the platform specific styling to the element that does have it by default. What's the point in using it if you don't want it? **Doctor @Peak** is right, don't do that!

Comment: Remove `-webkit-appearance: none;` Thats it. Btw. Why are you using it?

Comment: we use -webkit for chrome or safari right?

Comment: @vikas yes, yes we do

Comment: I need just a black 1px solid box for my design. But why the check disappers? How to style the check?

Comment: only way to do is with a image, loads of work for such a simple thing, I would recommend to use standard checkboxes

Comment: @TomPeak see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14058576/703717)

Comment: ok, found a lot about that. There is really no way to style a checkbox? wtf?