# I want add some css on input checkbox

Tags: jquery, html, css, input, checkbox

I want add some css on input checkbox for all browsers (chrome, firefox, ie - 6 7 8) if jquery is the last option please do let me know and must supporting for all browsers

can anyone help how can i do that..?

Comment: That's the similare question, see answer at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120879/css-checkbox-input-styling

Answer (score 4):

Use an [attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors)

```
[type=checkbox] {
    /* some rules */
}
```

Comment: not working you rules Quentin do you have any other option...?

Comment: It [works fine here](http://jsbin.com/AgOfUVO/1/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#checkboxid").css({'height':'12px;'width':'12px;etc});
```

reference [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: If the checkbox has an ID why would you use jQuery over just selecting it with css as normal?

Comment: i am giving an idea that how add dynamic css  by jquery

Comment: not working your rules kk do you have any other option...? i tired your too but it comes error with red mark

Comment: removeetc in my code it is for just a demo and give name od fyour css property which you want to apply i will give you all set code thanks @ShresthaBros

Comment: this is my html code please have a look 



  <div class="custom-checkbox">
 <input id="check-3" type="checkbox" value="epic" name="genre"/>
 <label class="" for="check-3">Epic / Historical</label>
</div>

Comment: but in this where you apply css

Comment: i can change that from style but its not compatible for all browser i need to see my style on ie7 and ie8 too